# Reduce the number of semantic primes

Tags: semantics, natural-semantic-metalanguage

I was reading up on the semantic primes and I have the impression that the list is too long.

Indeed, if one were to add the term OPPOSITE, GOOD could be OPPOSITE BAD, DIE would be OPPOSITE LIVE and SMALL just OPPOSITE BIG.

Does such a reduction make sense?

Comment: LIVE isn't the opposite of DIE, not really. That means introducing OPPOSITE would only save a single prime. And you'd have to empirically test it, because the existing primes aren't just theorised, but test and proven to exist cross-linguistically.

Comment: You would shorten the list very considerably by doing that, but in the end it's an empirical question whether it reflects how we think - if you accept the idea in the first place. I doubt you're the first to realise this, so if it hasn't caught on, there's probably a reason...

Comment: Wierzbicka and Goddard's [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage) is an empirical theory not restricted to one language or type of language. It uses a large, but not too large ( ~ 50 in every language) set of language-specific primes and has been tested on dozens of languages.

Comment: >  there's probably a reason..., yeah and I was asking for it

Comment: Other words that are common cross linguistically are categorised under molecules, why isn't the case for those example? Just asking

Comment: Well, what you asked was whether such a reduction made sense - I was suggesting that it would make perfect sense but that it probably turns out we don't think that way -